# How does assignment to a boolean-indexed numpy array work?

Tags: numpy, indexing

If I have a numpy array `a`, then `a[a == 8]` returns an array that consists of all 8's. If I assign such an array to be 0, as in `a[a==8] = 0`, then I would expect that the object returned by `a[a == 8]` is being assigned to zero. Instead, assigns each element of `a` that was equal to 8 to be zero, which is obviously more intuitive. The problem is that I cannot understand how this comes to be by the rules of the language.

Comment: You can use a special class method `def __setitem__(self, key, value)` and define the behaviour of your class when an instance uses the indexing operator `[]` with assignment.

Comment: `a[a==8]` shares the same memory with `a`. You need `b = a[a==8].copy()` to create a new object with its own data.